# C++ cURL problems with csrf token

Tags: c++, web, web-scraping, curl, csrf

I want to post a query to **leetcode/graphql** and get problems' list in JSON. But I faced problems with csrf token. I'm pretty new at web stuffs and I can`t figure how to resolve the issue.
My code:

```
void request(bool isGet = true, std::string csrf = "") {
 
     static std::string query =
         "query allQuestionsRaw{"
         "allQuestions: allQuestionsRaw {"
         "title"
         "titleSlug"
         "translatedTitle"
         "questionId"
         "questionFrontendId"
         "status"
         "difficulty"
         "isPaidOnly"
         "categoryTitle"
         "__typename"
         "}"
         "}";
 
     std::string headers = "Content-Type: application/json";
     curl_slist* hdrsl = NULL;
     hdrsl = curl_slist_append(hdrsl, headers.c_str());
     hdrsl = curl_slist_append(hdrsl, "User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
 Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
     hdrsl = curl_slist_append(hdrsl, "Accept: */*");
     hdrsl = curl_slist_append(hdrsl, "Host: leetcode.com");
 
     CURL* curl;
     curl = curl_easy_init();
     FILE* fd = fopen("tasks.json", "w");
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://leetcode.com/graphql");
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
     
     if (!isGet)
     {
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, query.c_str());
     }
     
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?page=2");
     
     if (!isGet)
     {
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, hdrsl);
     }
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
     
     if (isGet)
     {
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "csrftoken");
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "csrftoken");
     }
     else
     {
         curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "csrftoken=" + csrf);
     }
     
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fd);
     curl_easy_perform(curl);
 
     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

At first I do GET request to receive csrf token. After that i parse token from the file and do POST request. But all response i get is: error 403, CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Any ideas how to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Kindly remove `>` from the code you have posted.

Comment: @kiner_shah, ooops. sorry. I've fixed that.

Comment: Not sure, maybe because of User-Agent being Mozilla? `User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)`

Comment: @kiner_shah, i was trying to use different agents, but none of them game successful result